# Generics What do I add to [???]? I know it is <T> and then something

Tags: java, generics

//You can only change ??? you can not change anything else in the code

```
public class Exercise {

  static [???] String get(List<T> strings, int element) {
    return strings.get(element);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    strings.add("Hello");
    strings.add("Dave");
    assert get(strings,0).equals("Hello");
    assert get(strings,1).equals("Dave");
  }
}
```

Comment: The question is to figure out what goes in the [???] to make it return strings.get(element)

Comment: @VictorPoloDeGyvesMontero The challenge is finding out what to put there without changing the rest of the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
static <T extends String> String get(List<T> strings, int element) {
    return strings.get(element);
}
```